# Input validation: Best practice when element to which aria-describedby is refering to is not in the DOM yet

Tags: reactjs, validation, accessibility, wai-aria

The situation is this: input fields (text, email, password) are tagged with `aria-describedby="some-id"`. In case user inputs do not meet the requirements, the element with the `id="some-id"` is rendered. Before that, the element is not present in the DOM.

When running the Google Lighthouse test, this is marked as a mistake since the id to which `aria-describedby` is refering to is not present in the DOM as long as inputs are empty or fullfill the requirements.

I was thinking about two workarounds:

1. Render the element with `id="some-id"` but leave it empty. And insert the content as soon a user input doesn't meet the requirements.
2. Render the element with `id="some-id"` AND insert the tag `aria-describedby="some-id"` as soon as a user input doesn't fullfill the requirements.

Any sugggestions what is best practice for accessibility in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aria-describedby` must point to an existing element. The `div` has to exist before the attribute is set.

Your two solutions are valid:

- you can point the `aria-describedby` attribute to an empty element, and insert the content when needed
- or you can set the `aria-describedby` when an error is detected.

Comment: Are we sure this isn't solving for a non-issue? Typical AT behaviour in my experience is any `aria-describedby` pointing to a non-existing element is simply ignored, which is basically what you'd want here, so what's the harm in just leaving it on?